# Windows Server 2012 R2: how to monitor logons?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

How do I check the users that have logged in on the server in the last couple of weeks? I suppose Event Viewer, but where exactly?

Answer (score 6):

It's all in the Security event log. Interactive logons, network logons, local logons, logons over RDP... whether your Security event log can store weeks worth of events depends on how busy your server is and how large your event log is configured to be.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericfitz/archive/2008/08/20/tracking-user-logon-activity-using-logon-events.aspx

The three-digit event IDs are for old versions of Windows. The corresponding 4 digit event IDs are for newer (Vista+) versions of Windows.

```
512 / 4608  STARTUP
513 / 4609  SHUTDOWN
528 / 4624  LOGON
538 / 4634  LOGOFF
551 / 4647  BEGIN_LOGOFF
N/A / 4778  SESSION_RECONNECTED
N/A / 4779  SESSION_DISCONNECTED
N/A / 4800  WORKSTATION_LOCKED 
* / 4801    WORKSTATION_UNLOCKED
N/A / 4802  SCREENSAVER_INVOKED
N/A / 4803  SCREENSAVER_DISMISSED
```

You may also be interested in configuring Advanced Audit Policies:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182311(v=ws.10).aspx

They allow you to capture even more events with more granular detail than you do by default. But it is not necessary just to capture basic "a user just logged on" type events.  But be careful about logging too much... excessive logging fills up your event log with clutter.

An event ID 4624 for example:

[image: 4624]

Comment: I was filtering 4624 events but they don't show me the username. The user id is in hex?

Comment: No... see the screenshot I added above.

Comment: I want to check the Active Directory for usernames and groups. I'm used to doing this on Server 2008, but on 2012 R2 I can't find the utility. Do you know where that is?

Comment: @Zopiro That's a different question than the one you originally asked.  Please submit a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a script which extract user logon **DateTime, accountname and IP** from security log and output it to screen and CSV file. If user logins with RDP it shows remote IP, if logon is performed from local console the IP is equals 127.0.0.1.

https://it4it.solutions/2022/01/19/extracting-windows-system-interactive-logon-information-to-csv-file-time-account-name-ip-address/